# Deployed responsive css looks different compared to local host

Tags: javascript, html, css, github, frontend

i'm very new at this.
My issue here is that when i look at my mobile css from localhost it looks fine, but then when it is deployed (tried both heroku and github) it looks really weird. And when i change things to extreme values it seems like nothing happens in the deployed one.

html:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

, Css:

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
@supports (display: grid){

    .super-container {

        width: 100%;!important;
        max-width: 100%;!important;
    }
    .container {
        width: 90%;!important;
        max-width: 100%;!important;
    }

    .btn2 {
        margin-top: 20px;
        width: 30%;
        flex-direction: column-reverse;
        color: black;

    }
}
```

}

tried both with and without support.
I added "!important" just to try if it makes any difference. = no.
checked that all my links are https and not http in the html.
Tried two different phones. Cleared cache. 3 different browsers (safari, google, and the samsung one).

The desktop version looks fine.

Link to site: https://ascoolarobban.github.io/resumegame/

Screen dumps:

[Deployed version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6cUU0.png)

[localhost version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bFKHV.png)

Answer (score 0):

Ok so i found a solution, if anybody get this problem in the future..Its not a pretty one but..
I took the autogenerated localhost-code and pasted in the bottom of the body and now it actually works..

```
   <script>

    (function() {
        var ws = new WebSocket('ws://' + window.location.host + '/jb-server-page?reloadServiceClientId=4');
        ws.onmessage = function (msg) {
            if (msg.data === 'reload') {
                window.location.reload();
            }
            if (msg.data.startsWith('update-css ')) {
                var messageId = msg.data.substring(11);
                var links = document.getElementsByTagName('link');
                for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
                    var link = links[i];
                    if (link.rel !== 'stylesheet') continue;
                    var clonedLink = link.cloneNode(true);
                    var newHref = link.href.replace(/(&|\?)jbUpdateLinksId=\d+/, "$1jbUpdateLinksId=" + messageId);
                    if (newHref !== link.href) {
                        clonedLink.href = newHref;
                    }
                    else {
                        var indexOfQuest = newHref.indexOf('?');
                        if (indexOfQuest >= 0) {
                            // to support ?foo#hash
                            clonedLink.href = newHref.substring(0, indexOfQuest + 1) + 'jbUpdateLinksId=' + messageId + '&' +
                                newHref.substring(indexOfQuest + 1);
                        }
                        else {
                            clonedLink.href += '?' + 'jbUpdateLinksId=' + messageId;
                        }
                    }
                    link.replaceWith(clonedLink);
                }
            }
        };
    })();

</script>
```